# Get the frequency of specific Characters present in each element of an ArrayList<String>

Tags: java, arraylist, char

please forgive me, I'm new to Java. This is part of my programme currently. Here I am reading a .txt file and adding certain lines of the file to an arrayList (which works as it should):

```
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    ArrayList<String> organismsString = new ArrayList<String>();
    boolean printLines = false;
    StringBuilder organism = new StringBuilder();
    if (e.getSource() == openButton) {
        returnVal = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
        if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
            //File[] file = hairpinFileChooser.getSelectedFiles();
            //read file
            try {
                br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
                    while ((currentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                        if (printLines) {
                            if (currentLine.startsWith(">")) {
                                // We have reached the next organism, so stop printing
                                printLines = false;
                                // Add the current organism to our collection

                                organismsString.add(organism.toString());


                                // Clear the StringBuilder, ready for the next organism
                                organism.setLength(0);

                            } else {
                                // We are still printing the current organism
                                organism.append(currentLine);

                            } 
                        } 

                        if (currentLine.startsWith(organismId)) {
    // Print this line, and start printing all lines after this (we don't want to append the current line)
                            //organism.append(currentLine);
                            printLines = true;

                        }  
                    }  
                    //Adds the final organism in the .txt file
                    organismsString.add(organism.toString());
```

However now I am wanting to count the frequency of the letters "G" and "C" in each element of the arrayList.

Currently I am able to count the frequency of ALL the letters present in the ArrayList but not for specific letters and not for each individual element. The code I have to achieve this is as follows:

```
 char [] c = organism.toString().toCharArray();
                            int sz = c.length;
                            int i = 0, j = 0, counter = 0;

                            for (i = 0; i < sz; i++) {
                                counter = 0;
                                for(j=0; j<sz; j++) {
                                    if( j<i && c[i] == c[j]) {
                                        break;
                                    }
                                    if (c[j] == c[i]) {
                                        counter++;
                                    }
                                    if(j == sz-1) {
                                    System.out.println("character " + c[i]+ " is present" +counter+" times");
                                    }
                                }

                            }
```

If anyone has any help or suggestions on how I might be able to achieve this then that would be much appreciated!

Hopefully this all makes sense but if not please just ask any question!

Many Thanks :)

Comment: Do you just want to count only capital "G" and/or "C"?  Or do you want to include lower case as well?

Comment: No just the capital ones. I want to total frequency of all capital G's and C's together for each element of the arraylist but having trouble achieving this although I know there's probably a simple solution :)

Answer (score 0):

You could have two int variables, one for the amount of Cs and one for the amount of Gs. Then, loop over the elements in the char array in turn. If the current element is equal to C then increment the C counter. If it's equal to G then increment the G counter.

If you just wanted the number of Gs and Cs in total, then have one counter and increment that every time you come across a G or C.

Answer (score 0):

I see two potential approaches to this.

1. Loop through each character in the String and increment a counter whenever you come across a 'C' or 'G'.  You don't have to convert the String to a char[] to iterate through the characters, just use `String.charAt()`.
2. Perform a temporary `String.replaceAll()` with the regex pattern of "[^CG]" which means you want to replace all characters that are not 'C' or 'G' with and empty string.  This will result in a string that just has C's and G's for which you can call `String.length()`.

Sample code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String data = "GGGGGCABCKDJ930495860CCCGCGCGCCCGG";

    // Loop counting
    int cgCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
        if (data.charAt(i) == 'C' || data.charAt(i) == 'G') {
            cgCount++;
        } 
    }

    System.out.printf("CG Count: %d\r\n", cgCount);
    // String.replaceAll with regex pattern
    System.out.printf("CG Count: %d\r\n", data.replaceAll("[^CG]", "").length());
}
```

Results:

```
CG Count: 20
CG Count: 20
```